# What is the standard error of the mean of multivariate normal distribution?

Tags: mean, standard-error, multivariate-normal-distribution

Assume that the non-diagonal elements of the covariance matrix are not zero. Please provide a closed form formula. I'm interested in the bivariate case in particular. How does the formula simplify in the bivariate case?

More precisely, consider the decomposition of covariance matrix $\Sigma$ into correlation matrix $R$ and diagonal matrix $S$ that lists standard deviation: $\Sigma= S R S$. I'm interested in $S$ and $R$, when $\Sigma$ is the variance of the estimate of mean of multivariate normal distribution.

Comment: The estimator will be a vector (since the mean of a multivariate normal distribution is a vector), so the variance of the estimator will be a matrix. When you say standard error of this estimator, do you mean the vector composed of square roots of the diagonal of this matrix?

Comment: Covariance matrix of the mean estimate will be always semi-positive definite symmetric matrix, no? I would like to know the full matrix. Just knowing the formula for the diagonal elements would also help.

Comment: So more precisely, you need the variance-covariance matrix of the estimator, not the standard error? Then consider editing the post accordingly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have an i.i.d. sample of any random vector $\{ (X_{1t}, \ldots, X_{pt}) \}_{t=1}^{n}$ where $\text{Var}(X_i) = \sigma^2_i$ and $\text{Cov}(X_i, X_j) = \sigma_{ij}$ then the covariance matrix of the mean vector $\bar{X}$ has diagonal elements $\text{Var}(\bar{X}_i) = \sigma^2_i / n$ and off-diagonals
\begin{align}
\text{Cov}(\bar{X}_i, \bar{X}_j) &= \frac{1}{n^2} \sum_{k=1}^{n} \sum_{l=1}^{n} \text{Cov}(X_{ik}, X_{jl}) \\
&= \frac{\sigma_{ij}}{n} 
\end{align}
for $i \neq j$.  So the covariance matrix of $\bar{X}$ is just the covariance matrix of the original vector divided by $n$.